# twilio calling Api <say></say> is not working

Tags: php, twilio

Hi guys I am trying to make a call using twilio and i want if the call is being answered then play a recording or convert text into speech which is provided in Twiml `<say></say>` my code to take the number to be called in input is

`

```
<htmL>
<body>
      <h1>Click-to-call</h1>
          <?php 

         if(isset($_REQUEST['msg'])) {
           echo '<i>' . $_REQUEST['msg'] . '</i>';
         }

        ?>
<h3>Please enter your phone number, and you will be connected to </h3>
      <form action="makecall.php" method="post">
            <span>Your Number: <input type="text" name="called" /></span>
            <input type="submit" value="Connect me!" />
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`
and the callback.php is as follow

`

```
<?php
require "Services/Twilio.php";


$AccountSid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$from= '+91xxxxxxxxxx';

$to= '+91xxxxxxxxxx';

$url = 'http://example.com/play.xml';

$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

if (!isset($_REQUEST['called']) || strlen($_REQUEST['called']) == 0) {
        $err = urlencode("Must specify your phone number");
        header("Location: index.php?msg=$err");
       die;
}


        $call = $client->account->calls->create($from, $to, $url );


$msg = urlencode("Connecting... ".$call->sid);
header("Location: index.php?msg=$msg");
?>
```

`
But when i am receiving the call it's not playing or saying anything which is written under the twiML.
Please help me

My TwiML code is as follow

`

```
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">Thanks for the call. Configure your number's voice U R L to change this message.</Say>
</Response>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by updating the From following

`$call = $client->account->calls->create($from, $to, $url );`

to

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create($from, $to,$url, 
       array( 
           'Method' => 'GET',  
           'FallbackMethod' => 'GET',  
           'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET',    
           'Record' => 'false', 
           ));
```

Since the array is instructing that how the link should be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Twilio Evangelist here,

Can you check which URL Twilio is requesting by looking in your [account logs](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/calls)?

I'm not the best PHP developer, but I think these two lines:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/play.xml';
$call = $client->account->calls->create($from, $to, $url . 'callback.php?number=' .            $_REQUEST['called']);
```

..result in your URL being:

```
http://example.com/play.xml
```

Otherwise, can you post your TwiML code as well? One other possibility - is to check you TwiML is cased correctly, all TwiML verbs have an upper case letter. So this **will not work**:

```
<Response>
    <say>hello</say>
</Response>
```

This **will** work:

```
<Response>
    <Say>hello</Say>
</Response>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have Updated the lines of my code which was having problem but the again its not speaking whatever i have written over there...
I would like to add that i have checked out the URL given by you in my account there is no record of requesting any URL

Comment: I've added some extra info, but could you post your TwiML?

Comment: Your TwiML is absolutely fine. I have just tested it, and it works for me. Can you check your Twilio logs for any errors? If everything looks okay, you might want to contact Twilio Support on help@twilio.com so they can take a look.

Comment: I have checked my Twilio logs they don't have any error message over there. Thanks for your replies..
Can you tell me one thing more that, is there any issue if i am running it from my localhost?

Comment: That should be fine, as long as the TwiML is not localhost. The URL you provided above is http://dev1.techencephalon.com/spotlight/mp3/play.xml which should be fine. Twilio must be able to route to the TwiML document.